# Android NDK project taking years to complete gradle buid due to Cmake checks

Tags: android, c++, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

For some reason, my Android NDK projects are taking years to complete a refresh or build. The problem only happens the first time a project is created or when the CMakeLists.txt is modified.

It may take 45 minutes perfectly, but after that, the next builds are fast (1min or less). During that time the IDE is unusable, as it doesn't have the correct project structure and configuration.

I'm using Gradle 4.1, Android Plugin 3.0.1, and NDK 16.1 (the last one at this moment).

This is what the log displays (full log [here](https://pastebin.com/keU9aqKb))

```
Executing tasks: [assemble]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
CMake Warning at <android_path>/Android/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:63 (message):
  Using custom NDK path (ANDROID_NDK is set):
  C:\Users\Fran\AppData\Local\Android\ndk-bundle
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  <android_path>/Android/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt
-- Check for working C compiler: <android_path>/Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: <android_path>/Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: <android_path>/Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: <android_path>/Android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: <project_path>/NativeTest/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a
```

There is any way to avoid all those checks every time? Or any way to fasten that process?

Comment: `There is any way to avoid all those checks every time? - What do you mean by "every time"? After detecting compiler for x86 do not detect it for arm? Unlikely. As for reusing cache obtained at "debug" configuration for "release" one.. By itself, CMake cannot do that. But some build tools are able configure once for several configurations.

Comment: By "every time" I meant to skip in some way the "Check for working compiler" and "Detecting compiler", as they seem exactly the same on each project refresh/rebuild (If I do it 30 times, the 30 times look like the same)...

Anyway, thanks for your answer, the problem solved by itself and it now always takes less than 10-20 seconds, don't know really why as I haven't changed anything since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment above, the problem solved itself without doing anything related to the problem, like changing the configuration or updating the IDE or the SDK... Wery weird...

The only thing I do was update the system (Windows)... maybe I had something broken that the update fixed...?